# How to get each channel's min value of a masked tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a  `mask` with a size of  `torch.Size([b, 1, h, w])`, which is acquired by `map > 0.5`, and a `tensor` with a size of `torch.Size([b, c, h, w])`. How can I obtain the min value of the `masked tensor` with a size of `torch.Size([b, c, 1])`?

I have tried `tensor[mask]`, but it returned 1-D result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a reproducible code and the desired result, that's is the way to get faster help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.where(mask,tensor,torch.inf).min(-1).values.min(-1).values.unsqueeze(-1)`

This works by replacing the masked out elements with infinity.

Here is a short working example:

```
import torch

B = 2
C = 3
H = 4
W = 5
tensor = torch.randn(B,C,H,W)
mask = torch.rand(B,1,H,W) > 0.5
out = torch.where(mask,tensor,torch.inf).min(-1).values.min(-1).values.unsqueeze(-1)
```